# Calling a callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I am not so strong in javascript.

I have a common function that I call from many parts of my code passing them some parameters.

Can somebody help me on

- how to define a new parameter for this function that should be a callback with no parameters passed from the caller (like many jquery plugins do)
- how to handle the callback call inside the function

Giving advice regarding the solution, if there's a better one, etc.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is actually quite simple.

```
function callback() {
    alert("I am in the callback!");
}

function work(func) {
    alert("I am calling the callback!");
    func(); 
}

work(callback);
```

Comment: Does it work even if the work and the callback are defined in different js files?

Comment: @Lorenzo - As long as both JS files have been loaded by the run-time it will work. Don't take my word for it though, try it out.