# making a JavaScript function with callback

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Write a function after that takes the number of times the callback needs to be called before being executed as the first parameter and the callback as the second parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a callback in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841454/calling-a-callback-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a bit like a homework assignment, so I'm hesitant to help you with your homework by answering the question for you ;)

Instead ... the basic idea is that you need to write a function with two arguments:

```
function (numberOfTimesToCall, callbackFunctionToCall) { //..
```

Inside you'll call the callback argument, using:

```
callbackFunctionToCall();
```

You'll want to do that a certain number of times, and in Javascript we typically use a `for` loop to do something a certain number of times.

For instance, to `doSomething()` five times, you could write:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, but don't forget to accept the answer (click the checkmark next to it) if it answered your question :)

Comment: don't worry will do sir