# How to return a JSON in GET method?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

Based on `xlsx` github documentation, i made this function to return a json object. This is a method i tried:

```
function getData(){
    var data; 
    var url = "Book1.xlsx";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    req.onload = function(e) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
        var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"});

        var ws = wb.Sheets['Sheet1'];
        data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        //console.log(data);
    }
    //return data;
    req.send();
}
```

My question is how can i return `data` so that i'll be able to use it in my other function? My problem is i have a lot of `XMLHttpRequest()` just to read my **Book1.xlsx**. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Callback function example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442321/callback-function-example)

Comment: Dup: [Calling a callback in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841454/calling-a-callback-in-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: Dup: [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Comment: How does this callback works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getData(cb){
    var data; 
    var url = "Book1.xlsx";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    req.onload = function(e) {
        var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
        var wb = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"});

        var ws = wb.Sheets['Sheet1'];
        data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        cb(data)
        //console.log(data);
    }
    //return data;
    req.send();
}

const d = new Promise(resolve =>
    getData(resolve)
) 

d.then(data => { 
    console.log(data) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Is ```Promise``` a built in function in JavaScript?

Comment: yep @AlexanderPaudak